# SUMIFS/SUMPRODUCT for 2D data with multiple possible values in 2nd direction

Tags: excel

I have been struggling with the following:
I have a data sheet as follows, from which I want to sum the amounts per week and groups of projects, where the group of projects is user input. This "data" sheet is schematically looking like this

```
   A         B     C     D     E     F     G 
1  YEAR      2017  2017  2017  2017  2017  2017
2  WEEK      40    41    42    43    44    45
3  ProjectA  100   101   102   104   100   85
4  ProjectB  80    80    85    82    80    82
5  ProjectC  60    60    60    60    60    60
6  ProjectD  105   108   112   116   120   122
```

Next step is that the question of which projects you'd need to sum, is user input, so in another sheet ("projects"), the user would input:

```
   A
1  ProjectA
2  ProjectC
3
4
5
```

Then in the third sheet, I would have to show the summed data per week:

```
   A     B     C     D     E     F
1  2017  2017  2017  2017  2017  2017
2  40    41    42    43    44    45
3
```

Now the big question is, what formula could I use in row 3 of this last sheet?
What I have tried so far is: (in A3)
`{=SUM(IF(data!B1:G1=A1;IF(data!B2:G2=A2;IF(data!A3:A6=projects!A1:A5;data!B3:G6))))}`

This gives me a `#N/A` error. If I replace `projects!A1:A5` by `projects!A1`, everything works fine, but then that's not much of a summation anymore :)
I have tried other versions with `SUMIFS` and `SUMPRODUCT` but those get me nowhere closer to where I'd like to be.
So, any help would be greatly appreciated.

(One last note, I am not able/allowed to change or add anything in the "data" sheet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Data!$B$2:$G$2=A2)*(Data!$B$1:$G$1=A1)*(ISNUMBER(MATCH(Data!$A$3:$A$6,projects!$A:$A,0))),Data!$B$3:$G$6)
```

[image]